# BZR or GIT alongside to SVN?

Tags: git, svn

At my job, we're using SVN as our VCS software. I would like to be able to do local commits and local branching, that would not affect SVN at all. Is it possible to just start a bzr or git repository to do that? I've been trying to run bzr-svn and git-svn, without much success, even following tutorial and reading doc, I seem to run in strange errors.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What sort of errors are you running into using bzr-svn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **convert** (one time operation) SVN repo to selected DVCS and get standalone repo instead of using bridge.

For double-system mode I'll recommend hg + hgsubversion (but this anyway will requiresome trick on pushing merge-commits back to SVN)

Comment: Sadly I can't accept conversion as an answer. I really would have liked to use bzr, but with the current setup a manual git initialization is the most I could manage. Other DCVS would crash and burn when I took the "usual" road. Maybe too big project, I don't know.

Comment: Well, for *me* Bazaar isn't choice, as "infant terrible" in DVCS world

Answer (score 1):

I've tried having a svn checkout as a bzr checkout and using svn-ignore on the .bzr folder.

It did not end well ! It was alot more hassle than it's worth. Now i just rsync the svn checkout to anouther folder and hack against that. bzr unbind is very nice for laptop hacking.